# Django not serving static files while STATIC_ROOT configured

Tags: django, deployment, django-staticfiles

I have a cloned project and I need to serve the static files with Django itself. It is my first time serving static files this way (in the past I used Nginx/Apache to serving media and static files). here is my try to serve static files by Django itself in production:

1- Adding STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT to settings.py:

```
...
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.environ.get('DH_STATIC_ROOT_DIR', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'))
```

2- project's directory tree:

```
├── my_project
│   ├── DH
│   ├── env
│   ├── apps
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   ├── static
│   └── templates
```

3- running `./manage.py collectstatic` and working well. here is `static/` directory's tree after this command (from past some static file exists in static directory because this project is MVT and loading templates):

```
├── admin
├── css
├── fonts
├── js
├── media
└── plugins
```

4- let Django serve static in production( in `urls.py`):

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

5- how `html` templates reference to static files:

```
{% load static %}
...
<link href="{% static 'plugins/global/plugins.bundle.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

For example, in Chrome (inspect) I can see the template page request to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/media/logos/logo-6.png` that `static/media/logos/logo-6.png` exist (all request to static files raise 404 HTTP status code). with this configuration not working even in `DEBUG=True` what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documentation [states](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development), serve not suppose to be used in production. If you don't want to use nginx or apache, then consider using [whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/). All you need to do is install it by `pip install whitenoise` and add these lines to middleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
  'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
  # ...
]
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it. do you know why my above config not working even by `DEBUG=True`?